# saveWidget fails with pandoc error 67 in R

Tags: r, pandoc

I've faced a problem with saving plotly diagram `p` as html file, when the filename `name` is not in English:

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, paste0(name, "_all.html"))
```

For English filenames it works just fine, but when `name` variable contains Russian characters it fails with error:

```
pandoc.exe: Could not fetch 28%E1_all_files/htmlwidgets-0.9/htmlwidgets.js 
28пїЅ_all_files/htmlwidgets-0.9/htmlwidgets.js: openBinaryFile: 
does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
```

In this example

```
> name
[1] "28б"
```

Is there a way to fix that problem?
Thank You very much.

Comment: I don't think Windows supports non-ASCII characters in file names... you should remove those characters from the `name` variable...

Comment: @mb21  well, that is not really true, it does. Moreover, there is no problem in saving the file, which `name` is in cyrillic, when saving the same name using `R Markdown` or `jpeg` library.